# Why these unit tests are failling?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Very simple stuff: I have a moon icon that is rendered when the value of `theme` is set to "light", and a sun icon for when it is set to "dark".

The moon icon onClick function sets the value to "dark" and the sun's sets the value to "light".

```
const Header = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = React.useState<string>('light')

  return (
    <header className="py-6 flex justify-between">
      <div className="flex flex-row gap-8">
        <div
          className="w-[2.5em] hover:cursor-pointer"
          role="button"
          aria-label="Theme Toggle"
        >
          {theme === 'light' ? (
            <BsMoonStarsFill
              size={26}
              aria-label="Moon"
              onClick={() => {
                setTheme('dark')
                document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
              }}
            />
          ) : (
            <BsSunFill
              size={32}
              aria-label="Sun"
              onClick={() => {
                setTheme('light')
                document.body.classList.toggle('dark')
              }}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

I am trying to write a unit test for this logic:

```
  test('toggles the theme', () => {
    render(<Header />)

    const themeToggle = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Theme Toggle' })
    const moonIcon = screen.getByLabelText('Moon')

    expect(moonIcon).toBeInTheDocument()

    fireEvent.click(themeToggle)

    const sunIcon = screen.getByLabelText('Sun')

    expect(sunIcon).toBeInTheDocument()
```

However, the sun icon keeps failling the test:

> TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of:
> Sun

Comment: I don't think `label` is the same as `aria-label`.

Comment: It is working for the moon icon. It just doesn't work for the sun icon (i believe it is because the sun icon is only rendered when the button is clicked, whereas the moon icon is rendered when is parent component is mounted)

Comment: I think you have to wait. There's some kind of fn that allows for you to wait for something to be rendered.

Comment: @bezzoon This is what I thought! This might be happening because React state update is asynchronous, right? I'm not sure on how to do it

Comment: await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getAllByLabelText(/Sun/)), {
      timeout: 10000,
    });

Should do the trick :)

Comment: If you're going to be using a lot of `waitFor` and other such logic consider using React Testing Library. It handles that boilerplate for you so you could `await userEvent.click(screen.getByLabelText('Sun'))`

Answer (score -1):

The click event listeners are attached to the icons themselves, not the container (the `themeToggle` element). You should be clicking on `moonIcon` instead or modify the component code itself.

```js
fireEvent.click(moonIcon);
```